# Viewing Unix Log Files

Tags: unix, system-administration

We are having a discussion at work, what is the best UNIX command tool that to view log files.  One side says use LESS, the other says use MORE.  Is one better than the other?

Comment: Not very programming related, but IIRC more can't even move backwards, I'll go for less!

Comment: does anybody seriously use `more` if they have an alternative?

Comment: In your discussion context, does it matter which you use?  As long as everyone can see the logs they're supposed to see, they can use the tool of their own choosing.

Comment: The only reason that this question is important is because of memory usage.  if someone opens a large log file with vi or cat it, it will bring the server to it's knees. I was trying to get answers from sys admins on what they suggest.

Answer (score 2):

A common problem is that logs have too many processes writing to them, I prefer to filter my log files and control the output using:

`tail -f /var/log/<some logfile> | grep <some identifier> | more`

This combination of commands allows you to watch an active log file without getting overwhelmed by the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any program: less, nano, vi, tail, cat etc, they differ in functionality. 
There are also many log viewers: gnome-system-log, kiwi etc (they can sort log by date / type etc)

Comment: From experience I know that using VI or cat on a large log file will cause issues on a server (memory issues to be more specific), so those options are not very feasible

Answer (score 1):

I opt for less. A reason for this is that (with aid of lessopen) it can read gzipped log (as archived by logrotate).

As an example with this single command I can read in time ordered mode dpkg log, without treating differently gzipped ones:

> less $(ls -rt /var/log/dpkg.log*) | less

Answer (score 1):

Multitail is the best option, because you can view multiple logs at the same time.  It also colors stuff, and you can set up regex to highlight entries you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Less is more. Although since when I'm looking at my logs I'm typically searching for something specific or just interested in the last few events I find myself using cat, pipes and grep or tail rather than more or less.

Answer (score 0):

less is the best, imo. It is light weight compared to an editor, it allows forward and backward navigation, it has powerful search capabilities, and many more things. Hit 'h' for help. It's well worth the time getting familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, using the standard terminal windows, there's one difference between `less` and `more`, namely, after exiting:

- `less` leaves less mess on my screen
- `more` leaves more useful information on my screen

Consequently, if I think I might want to do something with the material I'm viewing after the viewer finishes (for example, copy'n'paste operations), I use `more`; if I don't want to use the material after I've finished, then I use `less`.

The primary advantage of `less` is the ability to scroll backwards; therefore, I tend to use `less` rather than `more`, but both have uses for me.  YMMV (YMWV; W = Will in this case!).

Comment: Or you can use `less -X` if you want a mess. :)

Answer (score 0):

As your question was generically about 'Unix systems', keep into account that
in some cases you have no choice, for old systems you have only MORE available,
but not LESS.
LESS is part of the GNU tools, MORE comes from the UCB times.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `grep`'s line buffering mode.

1. Using tail (Live monitoring)

   ```
   tail -f fileName
   ```
2. Using less (Live monitoring)

   ```
   less +F fileName
   ```
3. Using tail & grep

   ```
   tail -f fileName | grep --line-buffered my_pattern
   ```
4. Using less & grep

   ```
   less +F fileName | grep --line-buffered my_pattern
   ```
5. Using watch & tail to highlight new lines

   ```
   watch -d tail fileName
   ```

   > Note: For linux systems.